# Cannot run bash file from PHP

Tags: bash, scripts, php

I am trying to run a bash file from a PHP file.
The script is in the directory `/home/hostitec`, which is called `registro.sh`
The php file, where I am running the bash file (giving him some variables as parameters), is in `/var/www/ftpdir/Hostitec/include/php`

The script is actually working, the syntax is fine. But the php file does not run it, maybe because of the directory

This is my **PHP syntax** for running the bash file:

```
$old_path = getcwd();
chdir("/home/hostitec");
$output = shell_exec("./registro.sh '".$var1."' '".$var2."' '".$var3."' '".$var4."' '".$var5."'");
chdir($old_path);
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
```

**FINAL PHP syntax**

```
$output = shell_exec("home/hostitec/registro.sh '".$var1."' '".$var2."' '".$var3."' '".$var4."' '".$var5."'");
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
```

Comment: What are the permissions of `registro.sh` and `/home/hostitec`? Can you do a `ls -ld /home/hostitec` and `ls -l /home/hostitec/registro.sh`? Also, can you check if `chdir` returns TRUE or FALSE?

Comment: @Antonio: it works on my computer. What is the output of running `php /var/www/ftpdir/Hostitec/include/php/yourfile.php`

Comment: These are the permissions of `ls -l` `-rwxrwxrwx 1 hostitec hostitec 1291 sep 4 14:53 registro.sh`. And this are the permissions of `ls -ld` `drwxr-xr-x 16 hostitec hostitec 4096 sep 4 14:53`. About chdir, it returns me this `bash: chdir: order was not found` @MrShunz

Comment: @Helio What do you mean with output? Sorry for my understanding, I'm from Spain

Comment: @Antonio what is "order" in `bash: chdir: order was not found` ?. I meant to check the return code of the **PHP** `chdir` function, which should return just TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: @MrShunz: it seems to mean `command not found` translated by words from a the Spanish `orden no encontrada`

Comment: @Antoni @Helio what I don't understand is that PHP function `chdir` should NOT return a string. That looks like a **bash** error, not a PHP one. As per manual ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php ) `chdir` should return true or false. As a simple test running a php scritp with just `echo chdir('/a/b/c') ? 'yes' : 'no'` gives a warning `PHP Warning:  chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2) in /tmp/test.php on line 2` and "no" as output.

Comment: @MrShunz: seems like @Antonio misunderstood me. I told him to run the PHP file with the `php` interpreter and he maybe ran `chdir` as if it were a bash command.

Comment: @MrShunz I thought `chdir` changes your current directory. The problem is that the php file and the script are not in the same directory, so I dont really know how to make php run a script from a different directory. Because since I'm running `./script.sh` it means that script is in the same directory, and as I said, its not...

Comment: @Antonio: you can execute an absolute path: `shell_exec("/home/hostitec/registro.sh '".$var1."' '".$var2."' '".$var3."' '".$var4."' '".$var5."'");`

Comment: @Helio problem solved

Comment: Ok, I would encourage you to answer yourself with the solution so it helps the next user with the same problem.